# What does 'cannot assign to dereference' mean in go?

Tags: go, pointers

I'm studying Go and I had no clue for 'Pointer' until I saw it in the book. Here's my code:

```
var num int = 1
var numPtr4 *int = &num 
*numPtr4 = num
&num = numPtr4 // Error occur: cannot assign to &num
fmt.Println( num, &num, numPtr4, *numPtr4)
```

I've tried to assign pointer variable(`numPtr4`) to `num`'s memory adress(using `&`) but it failed. What am I missing?

And,

```
var c Circle
var c1 *Circle
c1 = new(Circle) 
c2 := new(Circle) 
fmt.Println(c, c1, c2) // {0 0 0} &{0 0 0} &{0 0 0}
```

I guess c1 and c2 are pointer variables, but they return their initialized value rather than their address. Why do they not return the addresses?

Comment: When using `fmt.Println` (or `fmt.Printf` with the `%v` format, which is more or less equivalent except for the newline), the `fmt` package does a lot of special case work with pointers to print *what they point to*, rather than just printing the raw value. The effect is that you can't figure out pointers using `fmt` this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case num is an int type with an assigned memory location. Golang won't let you edit the memory address of that variable. It's not a feature that would provide much value to the language.

In the second case golang is trying to assume what you want, which is to print the data regardless of if it's a pointer or not. In the standard case this is the right choice. There's not much that knowing the memory location can do for you except in this case when you're learning pointers.

To print the memory location use %p

Comment: Than why printing the pointer addresses (e.g. &num, numPtr) does work? Go doesn't assume in this time?

Answer (score 1):

In your example code `numPtr4 = num` also fails so I get two errors ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AhnURS3qwCT)):.

```
./prog.go:10:10: cannot use num (type int) as type *int in assignment
./prog.go:11:7: cannot assign to &num
```

I think the first error is fairly self explanatory; `var numPtr4 *int = &num` creates a variable `numPtr4` which is a pointer to `int`. You cannot then assign an `int` to that. Note that a simpler way to create `numPtr4` (with the same result) is `numPtr4 := &num`.

The second error (`cannot assign to &num`) is the one you are asking about; lets look at what `&num` is; from the [go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators):

> For an operand x of type T, the address operation &x generates a pointer of type *T to x. . The operand must be addressable, that is, either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation; or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array indexing operation of an addressable array.

So `&num` results in a pointer to `num`. Your statement seems to be trying to to create a pointer to `num` (`&num`) and assigning a value to that (which does not make sense because the result would be lost). The Go spec section on [assignments](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) prohibits this kind of thing:

> Each left-hand side operand must be addressable, a map index expression, or (for = assignments only) the blank identifier. Operands may be parenthesized.

*see the previous quote for the definition of addressable*.

You could achieve what you appear to want with `num = *numPtr4` (however as this boils down to `num = num` it does not make much sense in this context).

Ref `fmt.Println(c, c1, c2) // {0 0 0} &{0 0 0} &{0 0 0}`; the documentation for [Println](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) states:

> Println formats using the default formats for its operands and writes to standard output.

see [this section](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing) for info on the formats - the relevant section title starts with 'For compound objects...'. When outputting a pointer the thing you most likely want to see is whatever it points to (and this is what the default gives you). As others have noted you can output the value as an address with `fmt.Printf("%p",c1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [fmt.Printf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)'s formatting verb `%p` to render memory addresses:

```
fmt.Printf("%v %p %p\n", c, c1, c2)
```

Answer (score 0):

num is not a pointer and you can write into the memory in that manner so refactor your code(* represent dereference(setter) & represent reference(getter)),
`*` will take a memory address(&varname)
&varname represent where the memory
it should be like this

```
var num *int
var numPtr4 *int 
numPtr4 = num
num = numPtr4 // Error occur: cannot assign to &num
fmt.Println( num, &num, numPtr4, *numPtr4)
```